# Xcode 4 unable to create directory (permission denied)

Tags: xcode, macos

I am trying to build a plugin using Xcode 4, upon building however I get the following message:
/bin/mkdir -p /plugin1.app/Contents
error: Unable to create directory: /plugin1.app/Contents (Permission denied)

weirdly enough I haven't set any path as given by the error! Any Ideas?

I have also the following path in my locations (under preferences):
/Users/arming/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: If your target isn't very far along, you may want to delete it and rebuild it (no need to remove the source files). This behavior can often be the result of having accidentally deleted a setting in the build settings, but it can be hard to find. Especially with a simple target, it's usually faster to delete and re-configure the target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may change the file permission setting of the

> ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins

folder. 
(right click the plug-in folder and select the "Get Info". At the bottom of the panel, there is a section named "Sharing & Permissions". Set privilege of "staff" to "Read & Write")